# Checking for duplicates in an object array?

Tags: c#

I have the following object array, created from a custom class Room.  Before I add a new Room to the array I want to verify that the Roomname is not already in the array.  Here is a sample of what I am trying:

```
private void btnAddRm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Room[] roomArray = new Room[20];
test = txtName.text;

for (int i = 0; i < roomArray.length; i++)
{
     if(test != roomArray[i].getRoomName())
     {
          addRoom();
     }
}
}
```

`GetRoomName()` is the accessor that retrieves the `RoomName` from the class.  I guess my question is why is this code not working?

Thank you

Comment: What is not working with it?

Comment: Since `roomArray` is scoped to the given method and `roomArray[i].getRoomName()` will always throw a NullReferenceException -- is this the error you're getting?

Comment: yes! that is the error I keep getting.  I have the array declared at the class level and still am getting NullReferenceException

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will add the room as soon as the room's name doesn't equal the new room.
Instead, first check that *none* of the rooms have the existing name and *only then* add it:

```
private void btnAddRm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Room[] roomArray = new Room[20];
    test = txtName.text;
    bool exists = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < roomArray.length; i++)
    {
         if (test == roomArray[i].getRoomName())
         {
              exists = true;
              break;
         }
    }
    if (!exists)
    {
        addRoom();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fires `addRoom()` every time there is non-matching room in current array.

I think, you're looking for something like that:

```
if(!roomArray.Any(r => r.getRoomName() == test))
    addRoom();
```

or using `All` method:

```
if(roomArray.All(r => r.getRoomName() != test))
    addRoom();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should finish looping through the entire array prior to adding the new room.  With what you have if you have a new room name that doesn't match any existing rooms it'll call `addRoom()` 20 times.

```
Room[] roomArray = new Room[20];
test = txtName.text;

bool doesRoomExist = false;
for (int i = 0; i < roomArray.length; i++)
{
    if (test == roomArray[i].getRoomName())
    {
        doesRoomExist = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!doesRoomExist)
   addRoom();
```

You can also condense you're for loop by using the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) extension method, you will need `using System.Linq` to do so.

```
if (!roomArray.Any(room => room.GetRoomName() == test))
    addRoom();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others already stated your code does not make any sense. You create an array of rooms leaving all elements uninitialized (`null`). Then you check for existence of a room within that array. Also in your loop you "add" the new room each time an element has a different name. I have no clue how you want to add something to an array that is outside of the scope of your `addRoom` method. I hope this is not your actual code!

So first of all the room array should be created as a field of your class outside the scope of the `btnAddRm_Click` method.

Since you want to **add** rooms you should not use an array. Use a `List<Room>` instead. Otherwise you would need to know how many elements of your array are already initialized with a room. Also you would need to grow your array if the number exceeds the initial size of the array. This is exactly what `List<Room>` can do for you.

Your `btnAddRm_Click` event handler can then use LINQ to check for the existence of any room with the same name.
Please notice that you should use `String.Compare(name1, name2)` instead of `name1 == name2`.

```
private List<Room> _theRooms = new List<Room>();

private void btnAddRm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_theRooms.Any(r => string.Compare(r.Name, txtName.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0))
    {
        addRoom();
    }
}
```

Assuming that the room name is some kind of unique key for rooms you can also use a `HashSet<Room>` and then add the room anyway. `HashSet` will check for existence of the room. Your `Room` class however needs to overwrite `Equals` and `GetHashCode` then with `Equals` checking for equality of the room names.